# GWT - datagrid column with integer values

Tags: gwt, gwt2, gwt-2.4

I want to add a column to the datagrid in GWT, the column should show integer values. However, i cannot find any cell that can show an integer. This is my code

```
    Column<Trade, Integer> sellQuantityColumn = 
            new Column<Trade, Integer>(new NumberCell(NumberFormat.getFormat("##"))) {
                @Override
                public Integer getValue(Trade object) {
                    return object.getSellQty();
                }
            };
```

This shows an error - The constructor Column(NumberCell) is undefined.

For now, i can show this integer as a string, but is there any way of displaying integer values?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the answer myself,

The correct way of using the NumberCell is to use java.lang.Number as the data type and not integer or float.

```
        Column<Trade, Number> sellQuantityColumn = new Column<Trade, Number>(new NumberCell()) {
            @Override
            public Integer getValue(Trade object) {
                return object.getSellQty();
            }
        };
```